# Open Street Map tag to grab all emerged land

Tags: openstreetmap, osmnx

I'm looking to download the geometries of all emerged land (everything within the coastal line) in Python using OSMNX, but can't seem to find a general tag that would do it.

Right now, I'm using:

```
    t = {'landuse':['commercial', 'industrial', 'residential', 'farmland', 'construction', 'education', 'retail', 'cemetery', 'grass', 'garages', 'depot', 'port', 'railway', 'recreation_ground', 'religious', 'yes', '*'], 'leisure':['park']}
    land = ox.geometries_from_polygon(bbox, tags=t)
```

But I still have many holes...
So, in short, is there an OSM tag to grab all emerged land?

Comment: What white holes are you talking about? Your image has a lot of white but without knowing the raw data it is unclear if this is correct or not.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's all emerged land. That's what I was trying to convey :) I removed the image for clarity.

Comment: Are you talking about reality or the land use according to the OpenStreetmap data?

Comment: Land use according to OSM data. I would need a tag that encompasses everything that is not under water, basically.

Comment: Most countries post shapefiles of their coastlines. I think that would be the easiest way to get the land above water.

Comment: See also: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Coastline

Answer (score 1):

The additive approach, i.e. combining all sorts of landuses, won't get you all the way to the result you want. As you've noticed, you'll end up with white spots. You could get closer by considering even more tags, such as some values of the [`natural=*`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:natural) key, but ultimately there simply is land that is not covered by any such polygon in OSM.

Instead, you should look at [OSM coastline data](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:natural%3Dcoastline). As this can be tricky to process, you might want to get pre-processed data from osmdata.openstreetmap.de, such as their [land polygons](https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/data/land-polygons.html).